# Conventional tactics and munitions in Star Wars

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, tactics

Are there any known canon examples of the Empire using conventional military tactics and munitions in the movies and associated current canon? Besides the AT-AT and AT-ST for ground support and TIE fighters for air support.

I know that the Republic used artillery support and actually had battle formations etc. And that in *The Force Awakens* they actually had landing craft covered by fighters and the ground troops actually take cover correctly.

Also, at one point they wheel to cover a flank when Poe fires at them. All of this seems absent in the age of the Empire, and they appear to employ chiefly 'Run at the enemy and shoot them' swarming tactics.

I'll accept Legends answers, but I was hoping for some Disney canon explanation if possible.

Comment: Do you accept Legends explanations? My answer would be the same principle regardless of canonicity, but the rationale is different.

Comment: I'd accept Legends answers, but was hoping for some Disney cannon explanation if possible

Comment: Your last paragraph about non-blaster weaponry should be a separate question if it hasn't already been asked. And I think it might have...

Comment: @Null, You could be correct, but I feel it belongs here, in the intrests of the title involving both conventional tactics and conventional weapons

Comment: "Conventional" by whose standards?

Comment: @Rouge Jedi 'conventional' as in tactics employed by modern military and conventional weapons as in non-blaster based

Comment: Yeah, there's lots of info on non-blaster weaponry here. Search `[star-wars] slugthrower` and you'll find examples like [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76525/31936) and [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13690/31936). Since that last paragraph has already been answered and it's tangential to your main question, I've removed it.

Comment: @Null Thanks, I wasn't aware of slugthrowers. +1

Comment: Star Wars Battlefront is officially considered cannon and in it the AT-STs have mortars and the AT-ATs can call orbital strikes. Does that fit what you're looking for?

Comment: @Probst, Yes, that would definitely count

Comment: OK I'll make that an answer then I guess.

Comment: Are you talking about land battles only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Star Wars Battlefront video game is part of official canon and in it the AT-STs have mortars and the AT-ATs can call orbital strikes.