# Do any aircraft use slugthrowers?

Tags: star-wars, weapon

As described in this [previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76525/slugthrower-star-wars-universe), the [Slugthrowers](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Slugthrower) of Star Wars are *almost* on par with real world guns. **Have slugthrowers been used on aircraft in Star Wars as weapons?** For example, has an [T-47](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-47_airspeeder) (or any [airspeeder](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Airspeeder/Legends)*) been fitted with a high rate of fire slugthrower?

*I assume that some physics still apply in the Star Wars universe to projectiles in the vacuum of space, therefore the slugs would merely float around when fired outside of a planet's atmosphere, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you interested in answers from the Legends continuity or only current canon?

Comment: @KyleDoyle Either, just state which

Comment: You may want to add the star-wars-legends tag to your post to indicate that EU answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In canon, there appears to be at least one example. However, I am not sure if it exactly fits the criteria of your question. The canon comic miniseries *Obi-Wan and Anakin* takes place on the planet Carnelion IV in the midst of a conflict known as the Open-Closed War. Two humanoid factions, known as the Open and the Closed, fought for numerous years, each blaming each other for starting the war. They had so ravaged the planet that they were forced to used comparatively simplistic technology. Instead of blasters, both sides were armed only with slugthrowers, and they attached slugthrowers to the various vehicles that they used. One of the weapons of war used in the Open-Closed War was the **airgun**. It resembles a heavily armed blimp. Technically, it is an aircraft armed with slugthrowers. Here is a picture for context (the airguns are at the top): [image]

Answer (score 4):

Many ships used projectile weaponry of one sort or another, including railguns, slugcannons and missile launchers. The most prominent example of an airship using that sort of weapon in the movies was the [LAAT](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Low_Altitude_Assault_Transport/infantry/Legends), a transport craft used extensively by clone troopers during the Clone Wars. They were outfitted with mass-driver cannons capable of firing homing missiles, high explosive, armor-piercing or anti-personnel rounds. In the Legends continuity the [K-wing assault starfighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/BTL-S8_K-wing_assault_starfighter) was specifically noted to have mounts capable of carrying shorter-range slugthrower cannons.

Projectile weapons are even more effective and devastating in space than in an atmosphere as they do not have to contend with gravity and air resistance.